# Stick Footer Issue in Safari & Chrome

Tags: css, safari, google-chrome, footer, sticky-footer

My sticky footer works great in all the browsers expect Safari & Chrome, particularly the work.html page itself.

http://obliqueinteractive.com/creative/work.html

I noticed when i delete this css attribute from my style sheet, the problem goes away but doesn't allow for the footer to stick anymore

```
html, body {height: 100%;}
```

Could there be other css issues that are forcing the footer to act this way?

Comment: I don't see any difference between the rendering in Firefox and the rendering in Safari. Care to explain what should happen and what actually happens?

Answer (score 1):

First, hard to diagnose without seeing your code.  Yes there are definitely other css issues that can affect a sticky footer; namely padding on other elements.  Again, hard to diagnose when we can't see your code.

[This stickey footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/) is great and I used it a lot.

Comment: in google, the footer seems to be jammed up right under one of the divs

Answer (score 1):

code for the sticky footer and divs with padding:

```
body{
background-image: url(../images/main_bg.jpg);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
#wrapper{
width: 961px;
margin: 0 auto;
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto -104px; 
}
.footer, .push {
height: 104px; 
}
#work_colm{
width: 675px;
float: left;
display: inline;
padding-bottom: 40px;
}
#footer {
margin: 0 auto;
background: #292929 repeat-x;
height: 104px;
clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for this! Setting the height on the .push div did the trick for me. Other solutions will place a "clear: both" there, but IE7 and Chrome only worked for me after setting the same height on .push as the height on .footer.

Answer (score -2):

I made the following changes (to the floating footer element) and it works now in safari, opera, firefox, and chrome.

```
width: 101%;
margin-left: -8px;
```

I'm not sure if the 8px was just a fix for me or a fix for all but give it a shot and let me know