# Safari cutting off content at lower resolutions

Tags: jquery, css, safari

For some reason on [this site](http://www.davidfranktextiles.com/), Safari cuts off the bottom of the content (as in, doesn't render it at all) at resolutions lower than 1024x768. I can't replicate this issue in any other browser, and the only solution I've been able to find (which I've currently implemented) is to give the #content div a set height in Safari. The problem with this is the content is dynamic and largely shorter than its container, resulting in giant containers for little content.

Any help would be immensely appreciated. I've been staring at this for two days now and I'm at a loss as to why Safari is having so many problems with this. I've tried changing both the CSS and the jquery to fix it, but no dice.

Comment: I can see you've implemented my solution below - could you please accept and possibly vote up my answer if this has solved your problem mate?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to just get it at the bottom right?

It seems this is what you're trying to do...or more suitably even position:fixed;bottom:0;

give the footer a fixed position, not sure what id/class you're using but:

```
footer {position:fixed;bottom:0;}
```

Oh also - you might want to just give the content div a margin bottom of the height of the footer, that should put the footer always at the bottom (it's getting cut off for me in mac safari) and also allow enough of a gap beneath the content if it goes beneath the footer.

Comment: The footer position didn't actually make a difference in the way the content area rendered; what I ended up having to do was set the container height to 110% and set the navigation to position:fixed in order to keep it in the window so that the user didn't have to scroll. I'd avoided doing position:fixed for the footer for some reason in my initial build of the site that I've long since forgotten, but it doesn't seem to be doing any harm now so I'll leave it as is. Thank you for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to your CSS reset rule at line 38 in stylesheet.css

```
body,html{
    height:100%;
}
```

Also, see this:
[Stick Footer Issue in Safari & Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115317/stick-footer-issue-in-safari-chrome)

Seems Safari handles  with issues.